# How many records can JQGRID support?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How many records can Jqgrid will support? I uploaded and tested it for 140 000 records in Jqgrid. It is working fine for single user. In few days, my application will go to testing and production, there will be a scenario like, multi-users can upload data in Jqgrid.

Answer (score 0):

Because of data will be renderend on client preformance depend on it. 
Theorically it has no limit, unless integer pointer  used to index rows will be full.

In fact there are sample with lot of data on jqgrid site (up to 1,000,000 rows) that work very well, hovewer you should take in account the idea of using paginatio to reduce server and database load and networt traffic.